# issues with grouping with child nodes

Tags: xslt

i am new to XSL and facing issues to group xml elements with same name.
here is my input xml element

```
<Products>
 <Product type='Item' id='111'>
    <Group1>
        <color>Blue</color>
        <item>xxx</item>
    </Group1>
    <Group1>
        <color>Green</color>
            <item>yyy</item>
    </Group1>
    <Group2>
        <color>Yellow</color>
        <item>xxx</item>
    </Group2>
    <Group2>
        <color>White</color>
            <item>yyy</item>
    </Group2>
     <Product type='ChildItem'>
        <Group1>
            <color>Blue</color>
            <item>xxx</item>
        </Group1>
        <Group1>
            <color>Green</color>
                <item>yyy</item>
        </Group1>
        <Group2>
            <color>Yellow</color>
            <item>xxx</item>
        </Group2>
        <Group2>
            <color>White</color>
                <item>yyy</item>
        </Group2>
    </Product>
 </Product>
 <Product type='Item' id='222'>
    <Group1>
        <color>Blue</color>
        <item>xxx</item>
    </Group1>
    <Group1>
        <color>Green</color>
            <item>yyy</item>
    </Group1>
    <Group2>
        <color>Yellow</color>
        <item>xxx</item>
    </Group2>
    <Group2>
        <color>White</color>
            <item>yyy</item>
    </Group2>
     <Product type='ChildItem'>
        <Group1>
            <color>Blue</color>
            <item>xxx</item>
        </Group1>
        <Group1>
            <color>Green</color>
                <item>yyy</item>
        </Group1>
        <Group2>
            <color>Yellow</color>
            <item>xxx</item>
        </Group2>
        <Group2>
            <color>White</color>
                <item>yyy</item>
        </Group2>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

we are trying to get the output as below:

```
<Products>
 <Product type='Item' id='111'>
    <Group1>
        <color>Blue</color>
        <item>xxx</item>
        <color>Green</color>
            <item>yyy</item>
    </Group1>
    <Group2>
        <color>Yellow</color>
        <item>xxx</item>
        <color>White</color>
            <item>yyy</item>
    </Group2>
    <Product type='ChildItem'>
        <Group1>
            <color>Blue</color>
            <item>xxx</item>
            <color>Green</color>
             <item>yyy</item>
        </Group1>
        <Group2>
             <color>Yellow</color>
            <item>xxx</item>
            <color>White</color>
             <item>yyy</item>
        </Group2>
    </Product>
 </Product>
 <Product type='Item' id='222'>
    <Group1>
        <color>Blue</color>
        <item>xxx</item>
        <color>Green</color>
            <item>yyy</item>
    </Group1>
    <Group2>
        <color>Yellow</color>
        <item>xxx</item>
        <color>White</color>
            <item>yyy</item>
    </Group2>
    <Product type='ChildItem'>
        <Group1>
            <color>Blue</color>
            <item>xxx</item>
            <color>Green</color>
             <item>yyy</item>
        </Group1>
        <Group2>
             <color>Yellow</color>
            <item>xxx</item>
            <color>White</color>
             <item>yyy</item>
        </Group2>
    </Product>
 </Product>
</Products>
```

Am using below xsl file for conversion, but not getting output as expected

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="elements" match="/Product/*" use="name()"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[count(. | key('elements', name())[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elements', name())/*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping the child elements of `Product` by name, but this grouping needs to be done separately for each Product, and so you need a reference to the `Product` is the key usage

```
<xsl:key name="elements" 
         match="Product/*[not(self::Product)]" 
         use="concat(name(), '|', generate-id(..))"/>
```

Note how the key match doesn't have the `/` prefix, otherwise it would only match a root element called `Product` which would match nothing in your case. Also notes how it only matches non `Product` elements.

(And also not the use of `generate-id()` which generates a unique id for the `Product` element to identify it)

Next, you need to change your second template to match `Product`, not `\*` because `\*` is only going to match the root element. Then within this template, you get the grouped elements like so:

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('elements', concat(name(), '|', generate-id(..)))[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="elements" match="Product/*[not(self::Product)]" use="concat(name(), '|', generate-id(..))"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('elements', concat(name(), '|', generate-id(..)))[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elements', concat(name(), '|', generate-id(..)))/*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Product" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```